# Substr 0, -1 return only one character

Tags: php, substr

I have a problem with substr() function. 
`$a = AD26TM7i;`
I use this:
`$b = substr($a, 0, -1);`
`var_dump($b[0]);`
Produce "A".
I have 5.3.27 php version.
Someone know why?
On that page [CLICK](http://php.fnlist.com/string/substr) everything is ok.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you vardump only the first letter.
`var_dump($b[0]);` gives you the first letter of the string of $b.
Just use `var_dump($b);`